# how to highlight a table row when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to highlight a table row when mouse hover

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please define active and disabled row.

Comment: Its very unclear what you are trying to do, can you explain a little better.

Comment: iam looking to prevent column vise drag selection. like google event calender drag selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by assigning a `:hover` to the table-row, but style the table-cell after it:

```
table tr td {
    color: grey;
}
table tr:hover td {
    color: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/3koxqb69/)

Comment: not this one. iam trying to disable other rows using java script

Comment: What do you mean with disable?

Comment: currently iam developing a calender table,i need to prevent vertical draging